How can I compress an already installed version of Visual Studio
So I have visual studio 2019 installed on my pc I bought another pc and I want to ship it up to the another pc cause the internet in my region is bad :(,is there any way to do that or a software could help?
I considered copying the app from "C:/program Files/visual studio" but it won't work due to it's dependencies those are turned apart every where. thanks in advance

This question is probably off-topic for this site and would be better suited for SuperUser. But you will probably need an offline installer for doing what you want (which means you will have to download it once more, but from then on can install on as many machines as you want).

There are commercial and free tools for transferring installed applications, but it is off too in in SO.  You have to consider that VS installs the IDE, toolchain, SDKs and user profile to various directories, and sets various registry settings. It is not as simple as copying a folder.

VS is a very complex tool consisting of hundreds of components, including various system components. Chances that you get everything working correclty when copied to a different PC are minimal. Since VS 2019 is outdated anyway, I would recommend to download the latest version instead, even if that may take a few hours.

It's not supported to copy an installed visual studio cache to another machine to install visual studio. Consider to do an offline install as an alternative.

It's not supported to copy an installed visual studio cache to another machine to  install visual studio. If another pc has a poor internet,  you can use the command line to create a offline layout for Visual Studio and then copy the layout to your machine.
For example:
1.Download the Visual Studio bootstrapper you want to install and copy it into the directory you want to use as the source location for your local layout.(e.g:c:\localVSlayout)
2.Create a local layout. You can add workloads you need.
vs_enterprise.exe --layout c:\localVSlayout --includeRecommended --lang en-US 

3.Copy the local VSLayout folder to your another machine.
4.Install Visual Studio from the local layout.
Click the vs_enterprise.exe file in the layout folder to install it.
We can also use the new “Download all, then install” feature in visual studio installer to download the files before installing when have an unreliable internet connection or one that has low bandwidth.
